# The link interface of target "Ceres::ceres" contains: SuiteSparse::Partition but the target was not found

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, ceres-solver, gtsam

I am new in CMake but I want to use pybind11 to to create python library of my cpp code. My cpp code contain gtsam and ceres library. in creating CMakeLists file I used target_link_libraries to add my library but I have an error when I use Ceres::ceres. like this:

```
target_link_libraries(libscampi_ks
    Ceres::ceres
    gtsam
    # ${GTSAM_LIBRARIES}
    # ${CERES_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Even I used ${CERES_LIBRARIES} but in both I have this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresTargets.cmake:61 (set_target_properties):
  The link interface of target "Ceres::ceres" contains:

    SuiteSparse::Partition

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresConfig.cmake:272 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

I installed ceres correctly and my cpp code also run correctly but today I find this problem. I don't know if I have a problem in my CMakeLists file.
(furthere more if I cmake.. and make this file without Ceres::ceres in target_link_libraries it run but in using python module I give this error: "double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)" that I think maybe it is beacause of not using Ceres::ceres in my target_link_libraries)

thanks anyone if can help me.

Also here is my full version of my CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.3)
project(scampi_factor_graph_solver)

# find_package (PythonLibs COMPONENTS)
# include_directories(/usr/include/python3.8/)

# set(GTSAM_DIR /home/mohammad/gtsam)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
#SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mfma")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mavx2 -mfma")
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

include(cotire)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)
# find_package(Ceres REQUIRED COMPONENTS EigenSparse SparseLinearAlgebraLibrary LAPACK SuiteSparse SchurSpecializations)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
# Find the manif library: https://github.com/artivis/manif/blob/devel/docs/pages/cpp/Quick-start.md
find_package(manif REQUIRED)

###### GTSAM STUFF STARTS HERE
# Include GTSAM CMake tools
find_package(GTSAMCMakeTools)
if(GTSAMCMakeTools_FOUND)  
  message(STATUS "GTSAMCMakeTools FOUND ${GTSAM_VERSION}")
else()
  message(STATUS "GTSAMCMakeTools Not Found")
endif()
#include(GtsamBuildTypes) # Load build type flags and default to Debug mode
#include(GtsamTesting)    # Easy functions for creating unit tests and scripts
#include(GtsamMatlabWrap) # Automatic MATLAB wrapper generation

# Ensure that local folder is searched before library folders
#include_directories(BEFORE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

###################################################################################
# Find GTSAM components
find_package(GTSAM REQUIRED) # Uses installed package
include_directories(${GTSAM_INCLUDE_DIR})
if(GTSAM_FOUND)  
  message(STATUS "Found GTSAM ${GTSAM_VERSION}")
else()
  message(STATUS "GTSAM Not Found")
endif()
###################################################################################
# Build static library from common sources
#set(CONVENIENCE_LIB_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
#add_library(${CONVENIENCE_LIB_NAME} STATIC include/car/car_lib.h src/car_lib.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${CONVENIENCE_LIB_NAME} gtsam)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(TBB REQUIRED)
###### GTSAM STUFF ENDS HER


include_directories(include
    lib/include
    gtsam
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${manif_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GTSAM_INCLUDE_DIR}
)


add_library(libscampi_ks
    lib/src/scampi.cpp
    )


target_link_libraries(libscampi_ks
    Ceres::ceres
    gtsam
    # ${GTSAM_LIBRARIES}
    # ${CERES_LIBRARIES}
)


cotire(libscampi_ks)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

pybind11_add_module(scampi_fg src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(scampi_fg PRIVATE
                      Ceres::ceres
                      gtsam
                      libscampi_ks
                      ${SCAMPI_SOLVER_LIBS}
                      # ${GTSAM_LIBRARIES}
                      # ${CERES_LIBRARIES}
)

target_compile_definitions(scampi_fg
                           PRIVATE VERSION_INFO=${VERSION_INFO})
```

Comment: try adding `find_package(SuiteSparse REQUIRED)` before `find_package(Ceres`

Comment: I tried but it gave me error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSuiteSparse.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "SuiteSparse", but CMake did not find one.

also I installed [this](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse), but didn't work. @AlanBirtles

Comment: when you installed ceres did you have suitesparse installed first?

Comment: no, I installed suitesparse today by `conda install -c conda-forge suitesparse` .  base on [conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/suitesparse). but ceres-solver had installed before.

Comment: you'll probably want to install everything via conda or nothing via conda, mixing installations methods is rarely a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by reinstalling SuiteSparse from [this repo](https://github.com/MohammadrezaDindarloo/SuiteSparse)